# Div position issue in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have a div class"`selection-detail-container`" and I am displaying it as an pop up window.

Css on div is

```
.selection-detail-container {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left:10%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 65%;
    background-color:#003768;
    border:1px solid #003768;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;

}
```

Now this div is opening properly in all browsers except Safari. On the iPad Air, on Safari, when you scroll away from the first page of content and click on any piece of tagged data, the window(div) opens off the screen/back at the top of the content/browser window.  In order to see it, you have to scroll back up to the top of the document.  This  is not an issue on desktop environments.

Please help.

Comment: Need a visualization of the bug or a working example.

Comment: I'll try to create a dummy example. as i cant share my running application

Comment: Hi Odedta, Not able to create dummy Application and cant share running my application due to security issues. My pop up opens up on the top and didn't considering the parent screen is scrolled down.

Comment: Sorry Anamika, the code you posted shouldn't have any special effect on the Safari browser, it is most likely being caused by something else.